# I get a "database does not exist error" when running unit tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing

Every time I run the command:

```
rake test test/models/post_test.rb test_the_truth
```

I get the following error:

```
`initialize': FATAL:  database "knome_test" does not exist (PG::Error).
```

Can someone explain and help me to debug it?

Comment: I have the database and still showing me the error. I have done rake db:test:clone after creating db in testing environment

Answer (score 8):

It sounds like you have not created the database.

Try running the following to create, migrate, then prepare your test database.

```
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
rake db:test:prepare
```

Comment: I have the database and still showing me the error. I have done rake db:test:clone after creating db in testing environment

Comment: In my case `rake db:test:prepare` was enough :).

Answer (score -1):

You have create a new database in postgres and update database.yml "test" section with that db_name, username & password. The same way you have done in "development" section.